# Combine ucwords and strtoupper in a string with symbol as separator

Tags: php

I have some of string which look like this :

> "MOULDED WIRE BRA #viag19203"
>
> "moulded non wire bra #viag19202"

how to make all the string to become like :

> "Moulded Wire Bra #VIAG19203"
>
> "Moulded non-Wire Bra #VIAG19203"

so every word before # is using ucwords, and everything after '#' is strtotupper

the closest solution i can find for now is

```
<?php
$txt = "moulded non wire bra #viag19202";

echo implode('#', array_map('ucwords', explode('#', $txt)));

?>
```

the result is :

> Moulded Non Wire Bra #Viag19202

how to make all the letter after # uppercase?

Comment: Have a look at regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php)  to find first position of **#**: Then you can slice your string with [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php) and use ucwords on first and the strtoupper on second:

```php
$txt = "moulded non wire bra #viag19202";
$position = strpos($txt, '#'); 
$first = ucwords(substr($txt, 0, $pos));
$second = strtoupper(substr($txt, $pos));
$label = $first.$second;

echo $label;
```

Or using implode and explode. You had an error, because you was using ucwords on each element of array:

```php
$txt = "moulded non wire bra #viag19202";
$chunks = explode('#', $txt);
$chunks[0] = ucwords($chunks[0]);
$chunks[1] = strtoupper($chunks[1]); //#viag19202" -->> #VIAG19203

echo implode('#', $chunks);
```